# Как в IDEA можно посмотреть все перегрузки и список доступных параметров?

Tags: intellij-idea

Гугл говорит, что это CTRL+SPACE, но если я нажимаю это сочетание, то вижу такой трешь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так?

Если это важно, то проект на SCALA.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что раз подчеркивает метод красным, значит его нет у данного класса вообще, соответственно нет перезагрузок и параметров.

Comment: Все есть- это просто нет перегрузки без аргументов. Это стандартный метод из Java.

Comment: Вот https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html . Если я туда забью строку, то он перестанет быть красным.

Comment: У меня без всяких сочетаний клавиш после паузы выводит https://i.stack.imgur.com/oypUM.png . Точно правильный Paths импортирован?

Comment: @insolor да, через CTRL+Click куда нужно попадаю. А настройки у тебя дефолтные?

Comment: По идее да, все по дефолту

Comment: Если я уберу скобочки и добавлю, то инфа есть, но если я выйду из скобок и вернусь назад, то не могу ее увидеть снова=(

Comment: Курсор должен быть на самом методе get, а не внутри скобок, тогда CTRL+SPACE сработает. Второй способ внутри скобок это CTRL + P. Еще несколько советов можно тут почитать: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-reference-information.html#inlay-hints